# How do I merge a geom_bar and a dpois stat_function together in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to merge my 2 plots in r. I currently have 2 ggplots like so:

```
ggplot(dataset2, aes(x = factor(V1))) +
    geom_bar(alpha = 0.2)
    
ggplot(dataset2, aes(V1)) +
    stat_function(geom="line", n=10, fun=dpois, args=list(1.602))
```

This gives me the plot:
[bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF9Bq.png)
and [dpois plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DieIo.png).

I'm trying to merge them into something like this [merged plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Iyg.png).
I have tried to do add `stat_function` to the first ggplot like this:

```
    ggplot(dataset2, aes(x = factor(V1))) +
      geom_bar(alpha = 0.2) +
      stat_function(geom="line", n=10, fun=dpois, args=list(1.602))
```

but that gives me the plot [plot of flat-lined dpois](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMVzS.png).

How do I create a plot with both of the graphs looking like they did individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to transform one of the geom layers so that it is on the same scale as the other, then add a secondary axis:

```r
ggplot(dataset2, aes(x = V1)) +
  geom_bar(alpha = 0.2, aes(y = after_stat(count)/nrow(dataset2))) +
  stat_function(geom="line", fun = dpois, n = 11, args = list(1.602)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Density",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.x*nrow(dataset2), name = "Count"))
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(1)
dataset2 <- data.frame(V1 = rpois(100000, 1.602))
```

Comment: Awesome. Also the bit with passing an argument list to `stat_function`. Before I adopt it the wrong way: what's the advantage of passing the two params to `dpois` in different ways (*n* straightforward, *lambda* via argument list)? Thank you!

Comment: The `n` in the `stat_function` call is an argument directly to `stat_function`, whereas the argument list is passed to `dpois`

Comment: I get multiple warnings when trying the code you answered with above using the same data you sent. The warnings look like this:
`1: In (function (x, lambda, log = FALSE)  : non-integer x = 0.800000`
What does that mean?

Comment: It means that the function is try to estimate the poisson density at non-integer values. Try changing n to give you integer breaks (n = 10 perhaps)